# A variant of the wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I was working on the following generalization of the wave equation;

$u_{tt}-c^2u_{xx}+m^2u=0$

My professor had suggested a technique similar to d'Alembert's principle would work but I see no useful way of factorising  $(\frac{\partial}{\partial t^2}-c^2\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}+m^2)$. I also tried using the function $e^{mt}u$ but to no avail. Please suggest some way of doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let $\eta  = x + ct$ and $\xi = x-ct$ as in D'Alembert and you get a nonhomogeneous equation that you can still solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's write $u(x,t)$ as
$$
u(x,t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}U(k,t)e^{ikx}\,dk. \tag{1}
$$
Plugging $(1)$ into the PDE we conclude that $U$ must satisfy the ODE
$$
U_{tt}+(c^2k^2+m^2)U=0, \tag{2}
$$
which has as general solution
$$
U(k,t)=A(k)e^{i\omega_kt}+B(k)e^{-i\omega_kt}\qquad
\left(\omega_k=\sqrt{c^2k^2+m^2}\right), \tag{3}
$$
hence
$$
u(x,t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left[A(k)e^{i(kx+\omega_kt)}+B(k)e^{i(kx-\omega_kt)}\right]dk. \tag{4}
$$